# Angular factory missing in production - Rails/Angular App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, environment-variables, factory

I'm a student in a dev bootcamp school and created a metrics app which pulls data from an standalone API. To get some exposure to front end frameworks, I created the dashboard in Angular.  I created a factory which determines whether or not on the app is running in development or production by checking the hostname and assigning a variable to the API URL.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the factory works in development but doesn't in production.  In fact, when checking application.js in production via dev tools, the factory isn't there.  Below is the code presented in dev tools both in development and in production.

Development:

```
angular.module('blocmetrics').factory('apiFactory', function(){
  var api = "";

  if (location.hostname == "localhost") {
    api = "http://localhost:3001";
    return api;
  } else {
    api = "https://ryanhaase-api-blocmetrics.herokuapp.com";
    return api;
  }
  return api;
});

angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, apiFactory, $http){

  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + document.cookie;

  $scope.goToDomain = function(domainId) {
    document.location = '#domains/' + domainId;
  };
  debugger;
  // API call for users apps
  var domain = $http.get(apiFactory +'/apps').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.domains = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Error');
  });
});
```

Production (factory missing):

```
angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + document.cookie;

  $scope.goToDomain = function(domainId) {
    document.location = '#domains/' + domainId;
  };
  // API call for users apps
  var domain = $http.get('http://localhost:3001/apps').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.domains = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Error');
  });
});
```

As mentioned, I'm new to Angular and JS in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

-R

Application.js:

```
var blocmetrics = angular.module('blocmetrics', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'templates']);

blocmetrics.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
  .when('/domains/:domain_id', {
    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/domain.html',
    controller: 'domainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/setup', {
    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/setup.html',
    controller: 'setupCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/setup'
  });
});

angular.module('blocmetrics').factory('apiFactory', function(){
  var api = "";

  if (location.hostname == "localhost") {
    api = "http://localhost:3001";
    return api;
  } else {
    api = "https://ryanhaase-api-blocmetrics.herokuapp.com";
    return api;
  }
  return api;
});

angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, apiFactory, $http){

  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + document.cookie;

  $scope.goToDomain = function(domainId) {
    document.location = '#domains/' + domainId;
  };
  // API call for users apps
  var domain = $http.get(apiFactory +'/apps').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.domains = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Error');
  });
});

angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('setupCtrl', function($scope, apiFactory, $http){

  $scope.cookie = document.cookie;

  $scope.domain = {};

  $scope.update = function(domain) {
    $http.post(apiFactory +'/apps', {
      'app': { domain }
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('Success');
      $scope.reset();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('Error');
    });
  };
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.domain = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };
  $scope.reset();
});

angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('domainCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, apiFactory, $http) {
  // API call for an apps events
  var response = $http.get(apiFactory + '/apps/' + $routeParams.domain_id).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.events = data;
    $scope.app = data.data[Object.keys(data.data)[Object.keys(data.data).length - 1]];
    new Chartkick.ColumnChart("analytics", data.data.slice(0, -1));
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Error');
  });
});
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the actual `application.js` file. Are you putting the code for the controller and the factory in `application.js` or in separate files?

Comment: if it's missing that has nothing to do with angular....sounds like a build process issue

Comment: Do you minify the code?

Comment: The controllers and factory are all in application.js (added above).  I'm unsure whether or not the code is minified, but I did set:

config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the strict dependency injection syntax if you're minifying your production code.

```js
angular.module('blocmetrics').controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'apiFactory', '$http',
  function($scope, apiFactory, $http) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + document.cookie;

    $scope.goToDomain = function(domainId) {
      document.location = '#domains/' + domainId;
    };
    debugger;
    // API call for users apps
    var domain = $http.get(apiFactory + '/apps').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.domains = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log('Error');
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hey justind, this worked in development but in production, nothing. The factory is still missing and the dependencies are not there.  It is almost like the production code base on Heroku isn't updating.

Comment: I ran `rake assets:precompile` and it updated my assets in production. With regards to the factory, It looks like everything is working as it should now.  Now i'm just having issues with heroku finding my angular templates.

The console error is:
`GET https://ryanhaase-blocmetrics.herokuapp.com/assets/templates/setup.html 404 (Not Found)`